# What can I do about no VOC paint that stinks after it has dried?

Tags: paint

We just painted with brand new, but gone-bad NO VOC paint (Dunn Edwards in a dark teal). It went on smelling like good paint but when it dried it has a chemical sour smell mixed with vomit and dead animal. We live in the desert (Sedona) so humidity is not an issue.  Headaches and nausea are not fun. We sealed all offending walls with 2 coats of sealer primer (BIN Advanced) and another top coat of paint, as suggested by paint company, and it did not fix the smelly problem.  Then we got desperate. We have burned two boxes of nag champa incense, as well as cinnamon candles for days. We have washed the walls down with backing soda.... vinegar.... and natures miracle. Everything we do alters the smell, but does not clear it up.  Other rooms we painted with lighter tan color of same paint are perfect.  The windows have been open for days with exhaust fans going, and we are being held prisoner in the only warm room that doesn't stink. Once the room warms up the smell comes back.   After reading dozens of blogs on this issue and hearing over and over that paint company's do not own up to having a fix to this bad no-VOC paint issue, it looks like we may to have to tear down dry wall!   HELP .... Any suggestions out there would be helpful before I rip my home apart.

Comment: Heating the room to 120°F for a while, say 8 hours, should speed any odious drying process. Either a portable heater or the Sedonia summer could do that for you. Air the room out well when done.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to your problem directly but I have had a lot of success with Kilz Oil based primer. It is far from Low VOC and will come with a very strong odor initially. After the paint dries thoroughly the oil smell will subside and you can put on the top coat. I have used this primer to seal pet urine stains on sub floors that otherwise would have had to be removed to get rid of the smell.

Comment: That makes sense, oil based products tend to be much more capable.  Huge compromises must be made to have paint be water-based, and even more compromises to reduce VOC to modern SCAQMD levels.

Answer (score 0):

So this happen to me last night and I was freaking out!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I googled it and I cam across yours and another persons question. I also tried everything. Then I read someone saying it contains mold in the paint. so I told myself ill try bleach before I have to go out and buy the oil base primer. Well, it took 75% of the smell and I just did another run thru the walls. I will try this several times today. I know this is a little late but maybe if someone happens to get this disgusting paint problem they can try this. I hope that it takes it away enough where I don't have to buy more and can save that money. Good Luck to me and anyone else who might come across this....